# Kendo chart changes width when legend is clicked on

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have the following kendo definition:

```
$("#availabilityChart").kendoChart({
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "column"
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "bottom",
                },
                seriesColors: ["#1C64AF"],
                series: [{
                    name: availabilityDataSelector,
                    data: seriesData,
                    field: "metricValue",
                    categoryField: "month",
                }],
                categoryAxis: [{
                    type: "date",
                    baseUnit: "months",
                    labels: {
                        dateFormats: {
                            days: "MMM"
                        }
                    }
                }],
                valueAxis: [{
                    labels: {
                        format: "{0}%"
                    },
                    line: {
                        visible: false
                    },
                    axisCrossingValue: 0
                }],
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format: "{0}%",
                    template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
                }
            });
```

Firstly, the chart is not the full width of the containing div - which I would like to have.

Secondly, when I click on an item in the legend (I only have one) the chart resizes and becomes a 100% width - how can I have this from the start?

Lastly, I want to disable the click on the legend. I just want it to show but remove the ability to click on items.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent legend click behavior use the **[legendItemClick](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/events/legenditemclick)** event:

```
legendItemClick : function ( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
},
```

Unless you have some CSS overriding the width, the chart should automatically fill the container width.

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/gzjrGd)**

Comment: Thank you! Worked. I found the css problem as well, and now the chart is full width.